# Magento Facebook Social Integration

Tags: magento2.3, facebook

I want to integrate Facebook in my magento 2.3 site.
I am referring this doc .https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-integrate-facebook-with-magento.html
But as mentioned in step 2, i dont find Marketing > Social: Connect to Facebook option.
Can anybody help me with this.
Is there any updated doc?

Answer (score 1):

**Magento Facebook Social Integration** has been deprecated. Unfortunately, the **Magento Social extension** has been removed by Magento.

Magento dev docs stating the removal of Magento Social Integration https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/social-connect-to-facebook.html.

Magento Social Link module in Marketplace is also returning 404  https://marketplace.magento.com/shopialfb-facebook-module.html.

Please find the git link for the module  https://github.com/Magestore/devops-magento-2.2.2/tree/master/vendor/shopialfb/facebook-module. If you install it manually it won't prove to be useful for you since API service is also not working.

You can look out for any other third-party modules.

> https://marketplace.magento.com/ced-facebook-magento2-storefront-integration.html
>   https://marketplace.magento.com/mexbs-fbshop.html

Comment: do you know any third party module. I tried installing this , but this does not work. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-login-extension/

Comment: Please try these two modules demo https://marketplace.magento.com/ced-facebook-magento2-storefront-integration.html
https://marketplace.magento.com/mexbs-fbshop.html

Comment: Is there any free one?Thanks in advance